# Strange issue while configuring ID types for Embeddable class in EclipseLink-2.5.2

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, embeddable

In my current implementation I have separate entity classes for each db table. I am using JPA along with eclipselink-2.5.2. This is working fine for me but at some point when data is huge, it lags. That's why I decided to start using @Embedded, @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId. While doing this I am getting an error which is very strange for me. Here is the full stacktrace posted: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tjDudhatra/b955812e0d1a71cf97f1/raw/11ea458869e24baae744530417ac99bc877ed514/gistfile1.txt

Being Specific, let me give you the exact scenario in which case I am getting the exception. Consider this Code block which has three class. One is annotated as @Entity and other twos are annotated as @Embeddable. 
I know that in one class we cannot define @Id and @EmbeddedId and I have not done like that, then too while deploying server, I am getting the exception which only says that:

> [class org.apache.{SomeClass}] has both an @EmbdeddedId (on attribute
>   [id]) and an @Id (on attribute []. Both ID types cannot be specified
>   on the same entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")  
public class User {

  @ID
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="userCode")
  public String userCode;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
  public List<Address> addressList;

  ....
}

@Embeddable  
public class Address {

  @EmbeddedId
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="userId")
  public Long userId;

  @Column(name="address-line-1")
  public String addressLine1;

  @Column(name="address-line-2")
  public String addressLine2;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "phone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
  protected List<Phone> phoneList;

  ....
}

@Embeddable 
public class Phone {

  @EmbeddedId
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="contact_no")
  public String contactNo;

  @Column(name="country_code")
  public int countryCode;

  @Column(name="address_id")
  public int addressId;

  ....
}
```

Please let me know if more details required and any kind of help will be much much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Ohh I apologize, it's EclipseLink-2.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here I found the issue. I did some analysis and got to know more about embeddable and elementCollection. Here is the reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

So now I modified the code accordingly and it's working fine now. This is how I made it work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")  
public class User {

  @ID
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="userCode")
  public String userCode;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  public List<Address> addressList;

  ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="address")  
public class Address {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="userId")
  public Long userId;

  @Column(name="address-line-1")
  public String addressLine1;

  @Column(name="address-line-2")
  public String addressLine2;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
  protected List<Phone> phoneList;

  ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="phone")
public class Phone {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  public Long id;

  @Column(name="contact_no")
  public String contactNo;

  @Column(name="country_code")
  public int countryCode;

  @Column(name="address_id")
  public int addressId;

  ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A class annotated `@Embeddable` must not contain any `@EmbeddedId`.

`@EmbeddedId` is to annotate a field of type `@Embeddable` class in another class and mark it as the primary key.

Example :

```
@Entity
public class Project {
    @EmbeddedId ProjectId id;
    ...
}

@Embeddable
Class ProjectId {
    int departmentId;
    long projectId;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** : in your case, I don't think you want `Phone`, nor `Address` to be `@Embeddable`. Just mark them as regular `@Entity`.

Comment: Thanks for your response but can you elaborate that if I will not annotate Phone and Address class with atEmbeddable then will it work ?
I mean, if I want to embedded a collection of some class then that class must be annotated as atEmbeddable, right ? 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope, `@Embeddable` is really for a class that acts as a key. Is your database schema fixed ? If so, please provide tables for User, Address and link between them;